# Is it correct to use exceptions to prevent the execution of a system function?

Tags: c#

I do validations on the user side first, but it is possible to provide this class to a server, I am not sure, the client has validated correctly or not?
Therefore, in my business class, I always perform validations and throw an exception if the information is not valid
In my opinion, the use of exceptions is quite common and there is no red line because, finally, at the highest level of software layers, we can receive exceptions and manage them.

An example of my class is as follows:

```
public abstract class Worker<TArgument, TResult>
{
    protected abstract Task Validation(TArgument argument);
    public async Task<TResult> Execute(TArgument argument)
    {
        await Validation(argument);
        try
        {
            var result = await MasterExecute(argument);
            await Log(argument, result, null);
            return result;
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            await Log(argument, default, e);
            throw;
        }
    }
    protected abstract Task<TResult> MasterExecute(TArgument argument);
    protected Task Log(TArgument argument, TResult? result, Exception? error)
    {
        /*save log events*/
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}

public record Person(string Name, string LastName, DateTime Birthday);
public class PersonAgeDaysCalculate : Worker<Person, double>
{
    protected override Task<double> MasterExecute(Person argument)
    {
        var result = DateTime.Now - argument.Birthday;
        return Task.FromResult(result.TotalDays);
    }
    protected override Task Validation(Person argument)
    {
        if (argument.Birthday == default)
            throw new InvalidDataException("Birthday can not be empty");
        if (argument.Birthday > DateTime.Now)
            throw new InvalidDataException("Birthday can not more of now date");
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }
}
```

Comment: You seem to have some misconceptions about exceptions - especially as they relate to the .NET world where (unlike Java), exceptions should be reserved for _exceptional_ circumstances, so things like (human input) validation should not use exceptions because a validation-error there is not an exceptional circumstance.

Comment: The answer is ... both, when needed. .NET's already has [validation features and methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/models/validation?view=aspnetcore-7.0) that work both on the server and can generate validation Javascript. There are alternatives too, like FluentValidation. If you check the `Model validation in ASP.NET Core MVC and Razor Pages` you'll see that invalid requests can get an automatic 400 response with details *but* actions that perform their own validation don't throw and return a ValidationResult

Comment: It really depends on what a method does. Exceptions are for exceptional cases - situations that shouldn't arise. In a controller action, invalid data is expected so the best strategy is to return a 400 (Bad Request) to the client, possibly with details. Further down the stack, where invalid values *shouldn't* exist, an exception that short-circuits execution may be better. That's why .NET methods like eg `int.Parse` throw if they get invalid input

Comment: I think a decision should be made according to the circumstances, I don't think there is a red line here, because if it was a red line, they could have taken it from us according to the capabilities of the C# language, for example, they would have sealed it.

Comment: you can change exception before seen user.

Answer (score 1):

It's fine to use exceptions for "last chance" validation, which seems to be your case. However, in that case, you also shouldn't keep it as a separate `Validate` method - just put it in `MasterExecute` to make sure it actually gets called. Distinguish between what errors should be shown to the user by the type (e.g. `ValidationException` should probably be returned to the user).

It's likely still not the best method you could use, though. For example, the caller might want to know what happened - an `InvalidDataException` with just a string message might not be enough. It also means you're only going to receive validation messages one at a time, which is poor UX. Returning a *list* of validation errors is a lot nicer.

Comment: It's worth pointing out that .NET already offers validation and [ValidationException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationexception?view=net-7.0) and [ValidationResult](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.validationresult?view=net-7.0) objects

Comment: I have a custom exception that has a list of elements and other data, I haven't said anything about them so I have an easy question.

Comment: Often ValidationException is used in model properties.